# Google Analytics reports containing lines with a metric of zero : how to filter out these lines without cardinality issue?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

In Google analytics, until yesterday, this request :

```
dimensions="ga:date,ga:dimension2,ga:productSku", 
metrics="ga:productAddsToCart", startdt = start, enddt= end,
filters="ga:dimension2=~^[0-9]+$;ga:productSku=~^[0-9]+$
```

returned only the results where the metric was not zero. This enabled me to get full reporting of the purchases

(for one given day, I had a few hundreds of "totalResults"

It seems that the way the API has changed because this call now returns me

```
"totalResults": 1000000
```

I obviously cannot download all these lines, about 99.9%  of them being empty.  **Has there been any change in the way Google Analytics delivers these reports including only one metric ?** It seems an API call gave access to an unprocessed table, and that now this table is preprocessed (gaining a lot of lines in the process and making it impossible for me to get back)
**Is there now any way to access to this unprocessed data without having the cardinality issue I mention below?**

What I tried :  adding ";ga:productAddsToCart>0" to the filters list :

This seems to not solve a problem of [cardinality](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009671?hl=en): my custom dimension2 can take a lot of different values, and I lost the ability to download the full data for this day (because I now have "others" caused by high-cardinality, that is evaluated before any filters I can add on the metrics of the report)

Before this change I suspect in GA api, this problem only occured when I selected several different metrics in the report, and I could save myself by downloading one metric at a time, then doing the merge myself.

Comment: What is your dimension2? What is its scope?

Comment: dimension2 is an field that is used to identify which scenario affects the user. We run lots of AB test so we have at all time several scenarios running, and their combination quickly give us a rather high cardinality. The scope of the custom dimension is Session-level.